# retrieving null values from jq request

Tags: json, regex, command-line-interface, jq

I am new to jq and tried to extract only the values from the keys "taxonomy/definitions" as a list from this json file (it has many more objects than pasted here).

```
[
    {
        "taxonomy/relations": {
            "taxonomy/broader": 1,
            "taxonomy/narrower": 0,
            "taxonomy/related": 0,
            "taxonomy/substitutability-to": 0,
            "taxonomy/substitutability-from": 0
        },
        "taxonomy/id": "ZxHj_Wvj_39H",
        "taxonomy/type": "skill",
        "taxonomy/definition": "VM/CMS, operativsystem",
        "taxonomy/preferred-label": "VM/CMS, operativsystem"
    },
    {
        "taxonomy/relations": {
            "taxonomy/broader": 1,
            "taxonomy/narrower": 0,
            "taxonomy/related": 0,
            "taxonomy/substitutability-to": 0,
            "taxonomy/substitutability-from": 0
        },
        "taxonomy/id": "oRCp_wLd_dWd",
        "taxonomy/type": "skill",
        "taxonomy/definition": "OS/400, operativsystem",
        "taxonomy/preferred-label": "OS/400, operativsystem"
    }
]
```

I came to the following command:

```
jq -r '.[]."taxonomy/definitions$"' skills.json
```

However, it retrieves me null values. I assume that I did something wrong concerning the path or whatsoever but couldn't figure it out in a while ...

Comment: There is no object matching for the key `taxonomy/definitions` in your provided JSON

Comment: The JSON file is fetched from an API. I want to process only the values from the taxonomy definition. My desired output in this case would be:
```VM/CMS, operativsystem```
```OS/400, operativsystem```

Comment: Your attempt is using `"taxonomy/definitions"` with an extra `s` but your JSON has only `"taxonomy/definition"`

Comment: If the below answer solved your problem. You should consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is right, but the value iterator `.[]` operation does not accept the regex symbols directly. Which means your `$` anchor at the end of the `taxonomy/definition` is incorrect and needs to be removed. You can just simply do

```
jq -r '.[]."taxonomy/definition"?'
```

or if you want to use a regex based approach to match the `"taxonomy/definition"` exactly, you could do

```
jq -r 'map(to_entries[] | select(.key| test("^taxonomy/definition$")?).value)[]'
```